# Как сложить два числа из строки?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть переменная, где хранится строка

`number = "2+2"`

Как сделать так, чтобы python сложил эти 2 числа?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, так:

```
number = eval(number)
```

Функция [eval()](https://pythonim.ru/osnovy/funktsiya-eval-v-python) преобразует и вычисляет переданные ей в виде строки выражения.

Вообще, использование функций `eval()` и `exec()` чревато ошибками и проблемами безопасности. Подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

Answer (score 3):

Да, `eval()` хороший метод, но возможны *не очень хорошие* вводы данных, когда вы будете работать с `input()` (типа команды удаления диска С), поэтому:

1. Можно использовать условную конструкцию `if`:

```
number='2+2'
if number.replace('*','').replace('+','').replace('-','').replace('/','').isdigit():
    number=eval(number)
    print(f'Ответ: {number}')
else:
    print('Ошибка: введено не число')
```

2. Использовать регулярки (*регулярные выражения*):

```
import re
number='2x2'
x=True
number_split=re.split('[+*-//]', number)
for i in number_split:
    if i.isdigit():
        continue
    print('Ошибка: введено не число')
    x=False
    break
if x:
    print(eval(number))
```

Answer (score 3):

А можно вот так:

```py
number = '2+2'

print(sum(map(int, number.split('+'))))
```

Притом это будет работать даже со строкой `2+2+2`.